# Django passenger_wsgi.py issue

Tags: python, django, passenger

I run Django on an A2 Hosting Linux shared hosting account. Previously, I was using an old version of Django and Python. I was also using FCGI. I recently changed to a new server and am now using Django 2.1.2, Python 3.6.0. and Phusion Passenger.

I can't get the passenger_wsgi.py to load my website and I can't find the error log to try and resolve the problem.

The .htaccess file is in the public_html directory.

My app files are stored in:
/home/username/example.com/

The folder/file structure in the example.com directory is:
-media

-mysite

--- init.py

--- settings.py

--- urls.py

--- wsgi.py

-public

-tmp

-manage.py

-passenger_wsgi.py

#

**The contents of the passenger_wsgi.py file:**

```
import os
import sys

import mysite.wsgi

application = mysite.wsgi.application

cwd = os.getcwd()
sys.path.append(cwd)
#sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
sys.path.append(cwd + '/mysite')
SCRIPT_NAME = os.getcwd()


class PassengerPathInfoFix(object):
    """
    Sets PATH_INFO from REQUEST_URI since Passenger doesn't provide it.
    """
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        from urllib.parse import unquote
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME

        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI'])
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', ''))
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0]
        return self.app(environ, start_response)


application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```

The site produces an error (image below). I've been trying to fix it all day by tinkering with the passenger_wsgi.py file.

[image: Site error]

I can't find the Passenger error log file. I don't have any experience with Passenger. I've run out of ideas of ways to try and resolve the issue.

When I run 'python passenger_wsgi.py' in SSH, no comments are produced.

If anyone could help me to either:
(1) Identify what is wrong with the passenger_wsgi.py content or
(2) How I can find the Passenger error log on a shared Linux hosting account.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it'll be possible to diagnose anything without logs, but I've had the similar issues on shared A2 Hosting finding logs. I was able to find some Passenger logs in the "Errors" section of cPanel.

On the cPanel home screen, scroll down to the "Metric" subheader. There will be a link for "Errors" in this section. You should be able to find critical Passenger logs there.

Answer (score 0):

This structure of **passenger_wsgi.py** works for me on A2 Hosting:

```
import os
import sys

import MyApp.wsgi 

SCRIPT_NAME = '/home/user/domain' 

class PassengerPathInfoFix(object): 
    """ Sets PATH_INFO from REQUEST_URI because Passenger doesn't provide it. """ 
    def __init__(self, app): 
        self.app = app 

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response): 
        from urllib.parse import unquote 
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = SCRIPT_NAME

        request_uri = unquote(environ['REQUEST_URI']) 
        script_name = unquote(environ.get('SCRIPT_NAME', '')) 
        offset = request_uri.startswith(script_name) and len(environ['SCRIPT_NAME']) or 0
        environ['PATH_INFO'] = request_uri[offset:].split('?', 1)[0] 
        return self.app(environ, start_response) 

application = MyApp.wsgi.application 
application = PassengerPathInfoFix(application)
```